# Measure theory and itegration

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fermi-dirac-integral

Dear Mathematics community,

Def 4.1
($ M_1 $) 
Obviously it lives up to $ M_1 $ as any measure of the emptyset is zero, $ \rho(\emptyset)=a\mu(\emptyset)+b\nu(\emptyset)=a\cdot 0+b\cdot 0=0 $
($ M_2 $) Take <$ \{A_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{F} $ be disjoint sets. Then using  $ \sigma $-additivity we can see:
\begin{equation*}
\rho(\cup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_j)=a\mu(\cup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_j)+b\nu(\cup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_j)=a\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_j)+b\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_j)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}(a\mu(A_j)+b\nu(A_j)=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\rho(A_j)
\end{equation}
\end{proof}
I am doing some problems in measure theory and ran into problems with two problems. I sence that the problem is a lack of understanding in measures but maybe a clarification can help. 
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\rho(A):=a\mu(A)+b\nu(A)\quad \text{for }A\in\mathcal{F}
\end{equation}
Let $ \rho=a\mu+b\nu $ be a measure defined by (1). Prove that if a function $ f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is both $ \mu $-integrable and $ \nu $-integrable, then f is also $ (a\mu + b\nu) $-integrable and we have
\begin{equation}
\int fd(a\mu+b\nu)=a\int fd\mu+b\int fd\nu
\end{equation}
My attempt:
Assuming that $ f\geq0 $, we can then find a monotonically increase (or decreasing) sequence of non-negative, measurable functions $ \{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $, such that $ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=f $. Using the Monotone convergence theorem twice we can get the result that we ar looking for.
\begin{equation}
\int fd\rho=\int \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n d\rho= \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_n d\rho= \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int f_nd(a\mu+b\nu)=
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} a\int f_nd\mu+\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} b\int f_nd\nu=a\int fd\mu+b\int fd\nu
\end{equation}
I am unsure if it is permitted to do what I have from line 1 to 2?
Second problem:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
|x|^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}},& if x\neq 0\\
\infty, & if x=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Let $ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}$  be the function given by (2). Consider thge measure $ \rho_t=\lambda^1+\delta_t $ where ,$ \lambda^1 $ is the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $ \delta_t $ is tge Dirac measure accumulated in a point $ t\in \mathbb{R} $. Calculate
\begin{equation}
\int_{[0,1]}fd\rho_t
\end{equation}
For which $ t $ the function $ f $ is $ \rho_t $-integrable on the interval $ [0,1] $?
Here i guess I will  be able to use the first problem to split the integra into two:
\begin{equation}
\int_{[0,1]}fd\rho_t =\int_{[0,1]}fd\lambda^1+\int_{[0,1]}fd\delta_t
\end{equation}
But from here i have no idea.

Comment: Problem 1: No, that is not the way to go. Your sequence could be $f_n = f$ for every $n$. Better choose an increasing sequence of **simple functions** converging to $f$. But first prove (1) for simple functions. Then do the limit process.

Comment: Second problem: You did right. Now, note that $\int_{[0,1]}f\,d\delta_t = f(t)$ (if $t\in [0,1]$ - otherwise the integral is zero).

Comment: Made an eddit now, missing M2 am doing it now, was this what you meant?

Comment: What you added there shows that $\rho$ is a measure. BTW: Please edit thing like "Obviously a it lives up to...".

Comment: Do you know what a simple function is and that they are often used to define the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: How is anyone able to make any sense out of the question?(If there is a question)

Comment: Sorry small eddits in the contents destry the contents.

Comment: I do know what the simple function is thoug, I as you probably guess have no idea how they are used/define the Lebesgue integral